# Questions on Procedurally Displaying images in Oracle Apex

Tags: image, oracle, plsql, blob, oracle-apex

I am trying to use the `GET_BLOB_FILE_SRC` function to display an image that is stored in a `blob` column in a table.

According to the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_util.htm#AEAPI129) the following shows the function signature:

```
APEX_UTIL.GET_BLOB_FILE_SRC (
    p_item_name           IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_v1                  IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_v2                  IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_content_disposition IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
RETURN VARCHAR2;
```

- What sort of preprocessing do I need to do when the user uploads the image?
- how can I grab the mimetype and put it in the table?
- I am not sure what `p_item_name` refers to exactly. "Name of valid application page ITEM that with type FILE that contains the source type of DB column." is cryptic to me. How do I create the appropriate page item?
- Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Did you find any useful explaination of this function and its parameters?

Answer (score 0):

HedgepigMatt,
    Look at [Defining and Viewing BLOB Data in Oracle Application](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r31/apex31nf/apex31blob.htm) tutorial which is on old, but useful to you, also look at previous discussed thread [Oracle APEX display blob images directly in a report](http://oracle-apex-display-blob-images-directly-in-a-report).

For More Details Look at Packaged Apllication "Sample Database Application" In Product Tab in Your Workspace.

Comment: Second link is dead.